# Ant target calling

Tags: ant

I would like to call target backup.yes only if the condition is true.

```
<condition property="directory.found.yes">
<equals arg1="${directory.found}" arg2="true"/>
</condition>

<antcall target="update.backup"/>
```

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Can you expand a bit?  It can be done, but your question is not clear to me - you mention `backup.yes` in the question, but not in the sample code.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `<antcall/>`, do the following:

Imagine you're calling target `foo`, and you want to do a backup before, but only if that condition exists:

```
<target name="foo"
    depends="update.backup">
    <..../>
</target>

<target name="update.backup.test">
    <condition property="directory.found.yes">
         <equals arg1="${directory.found}" arg2="true"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="update.backup"
    depends="update.backup.test"
    if="directory.found.yes">
    <.../>
</target>
```

The problem with `<antcall/>` is that it is used when the dependency matrix Ant uses is broken, and it's used to force a task to be done before another task is complete. When really abused, you'll end up calling the same task multiple times. I had a project here that literally called each target between 10 to 14 times, and there were over two dozen targets. I rewrote the entire build sans `<antcall/>` and by using true dependency setup, cut the build time by 75%.

From my experience 90% of `<antcall/>` is due to poor target dependency management.

Let's say you want to execute target `foo`. (The target the user wants to really execute), and before `foo` is called, you want to do your backup, but only if the directory actually exists.

In the above, `foo` is called. It depends upon `update.backaup`. The target `update.backup` is called, but it depends upon `update.backup.test` which will test whether or not the directory actually exists.

If the directory exists, the `if` clause on the `update.backup` task is true, and the task will actually execute. Otherwise, if the directory isn't there, it won't execute.

Note that `update.backup` first calls any dependencies **before** it checks whether the property on the `if` or `unless` parameter for the `target` entity is checked. This allows the target to call a test before it attempts to execute.

This is not a mere side effect, but built into the design of Ant. In fact, the Ant Manual on Targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) specifically gives a very similar example:

```
<target name="myTarget" depends="myTarget.check" if="myTarget.run">
    <echo>Files foo.txt and bar.txt are present.</echo>
</target>

<target name="myTarget.check">
    <condition property="myTarget.run">
        <and>
            <available file="foo.txt"/>
            <available file="bar.txt"/>
        </and>
    </condition>
</target>
```

And states:

> **Important**: the if and unless attributes only enable or disable the target to which they are attached. They do not control whether or not targets that a conditional target depends upon get executed. In fact, they do not even get evaluated until the target is about to be executed, and all its predecessors have already run.

Comment: +1 antcall should be avoided at all costs - opening a new project scope, breaking the flow (depending targets of the called target will be called also..), properties don't get passed back to the calling target .. etc. It's the root of evil, maintaining such scripts is a PITA. Finally antcall is not needed anymore with ant >= 1.6 => use macrodef instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following

**In the other target:**

```
<antcall target="update.back">
    <param name="ok" value="${directory.found.yes}"/>
</antcall>
```

**And in the update.backup target:**

```
<target name="update.backup" if="ok">
```

But I think you can also do the following using the [if statement](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<if>
     <equals arg1="${directory.found.yes}" arg2="true" />
     <then>
           <antcall target="update.back" />
     </then>     
 </if>
```